# SQL Server I practice this code but its not executed

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

```
declare @databasename nvarchar(50),
        @timestamp nvarchar(50),
        @sqlcmd nvarchar(1000)

set @databasename = (select min(name) 
                     from sys.databases 
                     where name not in ('master','model','tempdb','msdb'))

while @databasename is not null
begin
    set @timestamp = replace(replace(replace(convert(nvarchar,getdate()),' ','_'),':','_'),'-',' ')
    set @sqlcmd = 'BACKUP DATABASE '+@databasename+' TO DSIK=' + ' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\'+ @databasename +'_'+@timestamp+'.bkp'

    exec (@sqlcmd)

    set @databasename = (select min(name) 
                         from sys.databases 
                         where name not in ('master','model','msdb','tempdb')
                           and name > @databasename)
end;
go
```

Comment: could you please explain more about your question?
what error do you got ?

Answer (score 0):

(1) **`TO DSIK`** should be **`TO DISK`**

(2) The **`C:\Prog...`** part should be enclosed in apostrophes. So, you'd better use **three** apostrophes in the beginning and the end of `path + filename` like **`'''C:\Prog...' + ... + ... + '.bkp'''`**.

(3) Query, correctly parsed, should look like (don't forget to replace the **`C:\Prog...`** part with the correct path):

```
declare
@databasename nvarchar(50),
@timestamp nvarchar(50),
@sqlcmd nvarchar(1000)
;
set @databasename=
(select min(name) from sys.databases
where name not in ('master','model','tempdb','msdb'))
;
while @databasename is not null
begin
set @timestamp= replace(replace(replace(convert(nvarchar,getdate()),' ','_'),':','_'),'-',' ');
set @sqlcmd ='BACKUP DATABASE '+@databasename+' TO DISK=' + '''C:\Prog...' + @databasename +'_'+@timestamp+'.bkp''';
exec (@sqlcmd);
set @databasename=(select min(name) from sys.databases where name not in ('master','model','msdb','tempdb')and name > @databasename);
end
;
```

(4) It's a good practice to end every line (complete command) with "**`;`**".